# How to dynamically load content from a list of different articles in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I want to load load content from database which are listed on one page. When you click the (heading-link), I want to navigate to a new page and load corresponding contents. Here is my html code

```
  div class="divpadding" *ngFor="let sermon of sermonData | async" 
  detail-push navPush="SermonPage" [navParams]="{sermon:sermon}">
  {{sermon.heading}}</div>
```

this is my code on .ts

```
 sermonData:Observable<Sermon[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
           public navParams: NavParams,
           private afauth:AngularFireAuth,
           private toast:ToastController,
           private sermon: SermonProvider,
           private afDatabase:AngularFireDatabase)  {

             {

       this.sermonData=this.sermon
       .getSermon()
       .snapshotChanges()
       .map(
         changes=>{
           return changes.map(c=>({
             key:c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
           }));
          }
        );

      }
    }

 }
```

And my provider is:

```
  private sermonListRef = this.afDatabase.list<Sermon>('sermon');
  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getSermon(){

  return this.sermonListRef;

 }
```

Comment: Are you talking about passing/sharing data between pages? From what I'm getting, you want to pass data from one page unto the page the user navigates to, right?

Comment: I want to list content dynamically from the firebase on page A and then when I click the list, you navigate to page B which loads the content dynamically and display the right content